# "Pagination not supported" error occurs when searching feature layers using the search widget

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I just upgraded to the 3.13 version of the JavaScript API, and I'm working on getting the new search widget (esri.dijit.Search) working in our application.

We have our own ArcGIS Server (10.1 I think) which hosts feature services, and I wanted to be able to search these using the search widget, in addition to addresses and such.

However, every time I try to search one of these feature services, I get a "Pagination not supported" error returned from the server. After a little debugging, I came to find that this was alleviated by removing the "resultRecordCount" parameter of the request that is sent in the query.

I snooped around in the code of the search widget and found that it's running a QueryTask under the hood, and passes a Query with the "num" property set to either the default value of 6 or a value I specify. In the documentation for Query (https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/query-amd.html#num), it's mentioned that the num property is only applicable for services hosted by ESRI.

The workaround right now seems to be creating my own locator service which wraps the feature query functionality, but I'm hoping this issue will get fixed in subsequent API versions. Or is there something I'm missing?

**EDIT**

Although I can't use any of our feature services in an example, since they're private, suppose we have a reference to an `esri.layers.FeatureLayer` *layer* which is hosted on an ArcGIS server version 10.1. What I'm doing is essentially the following:

```
var sources = searchWidget.get('sources');
sources.push({
    featureLayer: layer,
    searchFields: [layer.displayField],
    displayField: layer.displayField,
    name: layer.name,
    enableSuggestions: false
});
searchWidget.set('sources', sources);
searchWidget.startup();
```

*searchWidget* is a reference to an `esri.dijit.Search` which is placed in the UI. I initialize this widget with the following options:

```
{
    enableButtonMode: true,
    addLayersFromMap: false,
    enableInfoWindow: false,
    map: <esri.Map reference>
}
```

Given this setup, my expectation would be that I wouldn't get an error on the web request resulting from performing a search with the layer source selected, but instead I get the "Pagination not supported" error.

Answer (score 1):

as stated in the API reference, support for 'suggestions' or 'autocomplete' specifically is what requires the pagination support that was introduced in ArcGIS Server 10.3 and also available in ArcGIS Online hosted feature services.

API Reference - Search Widget
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/search-amd.html#enablesuggestions

if you're unable to search for features at all, please supply a simple repro case.  i'd be happy to take a look.

Comment: See my edit for a repro case.

Comment: i still can't repro.  what happens when you substitute your own service in [this app](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59331579/js/search-pagination.html)?

Comment: I get the pagination not supported error. Here's the layer info. http://pastebin.com/A3cKZTUJ

And it looks like the server is actually version 10.3, at least according to the containing service.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the similiar error here with ArcServer 10.3.1 and API 3.27.  My service is configured for "Advanceed Queries" and Pagination is supported, but get 0 results if the query is using the 'OR' operator.  Taking a cue from Mike's observation above, I mirrored the Search.js file locally and removed line 774:

```
a.num = c.maxSuggestions || this.maxSuggestions;
```

Now all is well and results are being returned in the suggestion.  This removes the 'resultRecordCount' parameter from the query, which seems to be the problem.